# Saving multiple check boxes into one database field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html, checkbox

I have a number of check boxes that relate to one field in a database. The checked values are recognised and put into a string but the value is not saving into the database. The table name and field name are both correct. Would anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong? Many thanks in advance.

*I understand the code provided is not secure but please note it is simply for testing the implode function before I apply it to my actual code.

My html code is:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="'apple'">apple<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="'banana'">banana<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="'pear'">pear<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="'grapes'">grapes<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="'pineapple'">pineapple<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="'strawberries'">strawberries
    </td>
</tr>
```

My php code is:

```
print_r($_POST);
session_start();

$p_test = $_POST["test"];
$in = implode(',', $p_test);

include ("dbConnect.php");

$dbQuery = "INSERT into test(testValues) VALUES($in)";
echo $dbQuery;
$result = mysql_query($dbQuery);
```

The $_POST and $dbQuery are being printed to the screen as:

> Array ( [test] => Array ( [0] => 'apple' [1] => 'banana' [2] => 'pear' ) [sbp] => N/A [submit] => Submit )
>
> INSERT into test(testValues) VALUES('apple','banana','pear')

It is successfully getting the checked values and putting them into a string but the values are not going into the database field.

Comment: Don't implode the data, it stops you performing useful searches on it. Use a join table: http://en.tekstenuitleg.net/articles/software/database-design-tutorial/many-to-many.html

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT into test(testValues) VALUES('apple','banana','pear')
```

Your SQL is trying to insert three values into one column.

Not sure why your HTML has the quotes included but they need to be escaped regardless. Switch to [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) (`mysql_*` functions are deprecated) and use parameterized queries. That way they will automatically be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$dbQuery = "INSERT into test(testValues) VALUES(". serialize($in).")";
```

And then when you retrieve it use `unserialize()` to get it as array once again

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this:

```
insert into test(testValues)
values
('apple,banana,pear')
```

thank your lucky stars that you failed.  As suggested by Quentin, that's an unwise approach.  On the other hand, we have this:

```
insert into test(testValues)
values
('apple')
, ('banana')
, ('pear')
```

which will make your data much more useable.